# AWK parsing top command output

Tags: awk

AWK code:

```
top -b|head -20|awk '/PID/,EOF {print $0}'|grep -v PID|while read line; do awk -v MYHOST=$(hostname) '{print "topstat,host="MYHOST",PID="$1" USER="$2",PR="$3",NI="$4",VIRT="$5",RES="$6",SHR="$7",STATE="$8",%CPU="$9",%MEM="$10",TIME="$11,COMMAND="$12}';done
```

The o/p line(1 line for e.g) is

```
topstat,host=host1.abc.com,PID=14 USER=root,PR=rt,NI=0,VIRT=0,RES=0,SHR=0,STATE=S,%CPU=0.0,%MEM=0.0,TIME=0:00.36,COMMAND=migration/1
```

I need the O/p

```
topstat,host=host1.abc.com,PID=14 USER=root,PR=rt,NI=0,VIRT=0,RES=0,SHR=0,STATE="S",%CPU=0.0,%MEM=0.0,TIME=0:00.36,COMMAND="migration/1"
```

Any help?

Comment: I added code fragments. Next time please do use the correct formats. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `\` escape character

```
top -b|head -20|tail -n +6 | awk  -v MYHOST=$(hostname) '{print "topstat,host="MYHOST",PID="$1" USER="$2",PR="$3",NI="$4",VIRT="$5",RES="$6",SHR="$7",STATE=\""$8"\",%CPU="$9",%MEM="$10",TIME="$11,COMMAND="$12}'
```